# Fast 2D image library/dll for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, 2d, system.drawing

after experimenting with VB.NET image and drawing classes, I am searching a new one that I could use.

The problem is that the actual classes are really slow and even a rate of 24 fps is too slow to refresh a moving 225x70 image and with double buffer. Using .FillRectangle with a brush is fast and could do the job, but the image is tiled behind the rectangle and does not move with the rectangle.

Do you have ideas of what I could do ? Please try to be clear in your answer if I need to install DLLs or things like that, as I am new to VB.net language.

*I already tried openTK, but it seems to be mostly 3D, I only need 2D. Should I use it anyway ? I can't find beginner tutorials for VB.NET.

Comment: You aren't trying to do graphics in Windows Forms, are you?

Comment: You're probably interested in DirectX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think XNA or GorgonLib would be the best options. OpenTK is good too, but I think it will be a little too complicated for just 2d drawing. There is also SDL.NET, but it hasn't been updated in a while and again, it's meant for 2d. The best 2d library I've used in terms of speed is allegro, but I'm not sure if there are any wrappers available for .NET.

Gorgon: http://code.google.com/p/gorgonlib/

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know how I can include/import these in my vb project?

Comment: I explored gorgon's features, and I find it bad because it needs to be installed with some other things on every computer that the game will run... XNA looks fun, but it's complicated to get. I haven't checked SDL yet, but I think I'll stick to Open TK. The only thing I need to know at this point to get it working is how to texture things with PNG transparent images...